# First letter upper case and other letters in lower case

Tags: text, control

I'm trying to make uppercase the first letter in string and lowercase other letters. Example:
Input:`eXample String` and output `Example string`.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\capmystring[1]{\capmystringaux#1\relax}
\def\capmystringaux#1#2\relax{\uppercase{#1}\lowercase{#2}}
\begin{document}
eXample String

\capmystring{eXample String}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case, `\capmystring` sends the argument to an auxiliary routine with an attached `\relax` token appended at the end.  The auxiliary routine reads two arguments up to the `\relax` (one would hope and assume that the argument itself contains no `\relax` tokens).  The way `TeX` absorbs arguments, the argument `#1` will be a single token, whereas `#2` will be all the remaining tokens up to (but not including) the originally supplied `\relax`.  At that point it is as simple as applying `\uppercase` to the first token stored in `#1`, and `\lowercase` to the remaining tokens, all of which are stored in `#2`.

Comment: Thank you very much and can you explain the code for me?

Comment: @user138843 I have added an explanation.

Comment: If anyone is worried about assuming that the argument contains no `\relax`, one could write something like `\endcapmystringaux` instead of `\relax`. (Then the assumption would be that the argument contains no `\endcapmystringaux`… you have to draw the line somewhere!)

Comment: Hi Steven, I tried to apply your \capmystring to my \mystr{} (\mystr is a macro  defined by : \newcommand{\mystr}{abc}), but nothing happend. So \capmystring doesn't work in this situation? How can I make it work?

Comment: @BioCoder `\expandafter\capmystring\expandafter{\mystr}`.  You could `\newcommand\xcapmystring[1]{\expandafter\capmystring\expandafter{#1}}`, to define a macro that expands the argument once before applying `\capmystring`.

Answer (score 15):

The `expl3` language can do this using Unicode data:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \firstcap { m } { \text_titlecase:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
eXample String

\firstcap{eXample String}
\end{document}
```

(assuming a new enough LaTeX2e format; for older cases, add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with pdfTeX.)

We might extend this approach to allow for language-specific case mappings

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \firstcap { O{} m }
  { \text_titlecase:nn {#1} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\firstcap{IJSSELMEER}     % Ijsselmeer
\firstcap[nl]{IJSSELMEER} % IJsselmeer
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about the packages that need to be loaded to enable `\firstcap` to operate on utf8-encoded characters such as `ö`, `ü`, `é`, `à`, `è`, `ł`, `ó`, and `ż`.

Comment: @Mico I've updated the answer here: currently the pdfTeX version with direct input of Unicode chars needs the 'burning edge' version to avoid an error: CTAN update tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks so much! We all appreciate the hard work you put in for us!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using the [`stringstrings`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stringstrings) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcommand{\firstcap}[1]{\caselower[e]{#1}\capitalize{\thestring}}

\begin{document}
eXample String

\firstcap{eXample String}
\end{document}
```

Explanation:
`\caselower` makes the whole string lowercase, the option `[e]` saves the result in `\thestring` such that it can be further processed, finally `\capitalize` does what it says and outputs the result.

Comment: Is there a way to extend your code so that it can handle non-ASCII-encoded characters, such as `ä ö ü é à ê ł ó ż`? (I picked these characters, more or less randomly, from German, French, and Polish keyboards...)

Comment: @Mico As far as I know the `stringstrings` package does not handle these special characters (please correct me if I am wrong). Thus I do not see a straight forward way to extend my solution. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

---

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution that works with all UTF8-encoded characters. This approach can handle UTF8-encoded characters because it uses -- in place of the "standard" Lua string functions `string.gsub`, `string.upper`, and `string.lower` -- the functions `unicode.utf8.gsub`, `unicode.utf8.upper`, and `unicode.utf8.lower`. These functions are provided by the `unicode.utf8` library, which is loade automatically by LuaTeX.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function first_cap ( s )
   s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "(%a)(%a*)", function(x,y)
          return ( unicode.utf8.upper(x) .. unicode.utf8.lower(y) )
          end )
   tex.sprint ( s )
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand{\firstcap}[1]{\directlua{first_cap(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}
\firstcap{eXample String}

\firstcap{Once upOn A tIMe i saw a BAT.}

\firstcap{ä ö ü é à è ł óÓÓÓ żĄĄĄ }
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* -- I just realized that I may have misinterpreted the OP's requirements: I had assumed that the uppercasing of the first letter in a word should apply to *every word* in the argument of `\firstcap`, not just the very first word. To make the uppercasing operation apply to the first word only (and thus applying the lowercasing operation to all other words in the argument of `\firstcap`), simply change the second argument of the Lua function `unicode.utf8.gsub` from `"(%a)(%a*)"` to `"(%a)(.*)"`.

Comment: One problem with the Lua UTF-8 support is it's not really clear what version of Unicode it is based on, and the treatment of contextual mappings is not documented. (Not a flaw in the answer, more a general frustration.)

Comment: @JosephWright - Thanks. So far, I've experienced only good results with the string functions of the `unicode.utf8` library, which is loaded automatically by LuaTeX. (I don't know if this library is loaded by "plain" Lua5.2 or Lua5.3 as well, though.) I'll keep an eye out for potential problems.

Comment: Not arguing with that: like I say, the issue isn't that it doesn't work but that it's not clear (to me) what _exactly_ the detail is. As someone who has read the Unicode docs on case changing, I would feel happier knowing what has been implemented!