# Loop over greek letters with pgffor

Tags: loops, pgffor

I am currently combining solutions proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57042/141947) for the loop definition of commands and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380507/141947) for the upper case letter forcing to define mathematical notations in a loop.

The goal is to have a shortcut for all letters of the latin and greek alphabets in bold font and upper/lower case.

For the latin alphabet the current solution works fine, but for the greek one it won't work.

So I actually have two questions here:

- 1: Is it possible to automatically loop over greek letters with pgffor, just like with latin letters
- 2: Is there a reason for my current solution not to work with greek letters

As usual, the answer may be very short or very long, so thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Command forcing 1st letter of argument to be capital one
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \firstcap { m } { \tl_mixed_case:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Loop over latin alphabet (working)
\usepackage{pgffor}
\foreach \x in {a,...,z}{%
\expandafter\xdef\csname \firstcap{\x}mat\endcsname{\noexpand\ensuremath{\noexpand\mathbf{\firstcap{\x}}}}
}
\foreach \x in {a,...,z}{%
\expandafter\xdef\csname \firstcap{\x}vec\endcsname{\noexpand\ensuremath{\noexpand\mathbf{\x}}}
}
% Loop over greek alphabet (non working)
%\foreach \x in {alpha,zeta}{%
%\expandafter\xdef\csname \firstcap{\x}mat\endcsname{\noexpand\ensuremath{\noexpand\mathbf{\firstcap{\x}}}}
%}
%\foreach \x in {\alpha,...,\zeta}{%
%\expandafter\xdef\csname \firstcap{\x}vec\endcsname{\noexpand\ensuremath{\noexpand\mathbf{\x}}}
%}

\begin{document}
$\Amat \Bmat \Cmat \Avec \Bvec \Cvec$
%$\Alphamat \Betamat \Alphavec \Betavec$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use e.g. \alpha in a csname, try out `\expandafter\def\csname abc\alpha xxx\endcsname{blub}`. If you want to build command only with Alpha you will have to write out the list explicitly. Btw: it is dangerous to define commands without checking if they are already defined.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I understand the warning, but what command are you referring to precisely ? Up to now I have met no incompatibility with these commands, I am just trying to avoid doing it explicitly for each letter.

Comment: Before doing \xdef\foo, you should always first do \newcommand\foo or add another test so that you get an error if you overwrite an existing command.

Comment: You have to define the list of names yourself, as it's not supported by `\foreach` like other easy loops.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the advice, I will add such tests. Before using the loop, I was directly using the `\newcommand\foo` syntax. I will try with the explicit list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the list yourself, but it's a one-time job. Besides, defining `\Alphamat` as `\bm{\Alpha}` will do nothing sensible, as `\Alpha` is not defined.

I believe it's simpler to directly use `expl3` instead of awkward `\foreach` with `\csname`, `\noexpand` and friends.

As usual, I omitted `\ensuremath` that does nothing good here: `\Amat` is a command for a math symbol.

I'm not sure what's the rationale for having a command `\Avec` that prints a lowercase “a” in boldface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

% Command forcing 1st letter of argument to be capital one
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bamboo_define:nnnnN
 {
  \cs_new_protected:cpx { #1 #3 } { \exp_not:N #4{#5{#2}} }
 }

\int_step_inline:nnn { `A } { `Z }
 {
  \bamboo_define:nnnnN
   { \char_generate:nn { #1 } { 11 } } % character
   { \char_generate:nn { #1 } { 11 } } % character
   { mat }                             % suffix
   { \mathbf }                         % decoration
   \use:n                              % just the argument
 }
\int_step_inline:nnn { `a } { `z }
 {
  \bamboo_define:nnnnN
   { \char_generate:nn { #1 -32 } { 11 } } % character
   { \char_generate:nn { #1 } { 11 } }     % uppercase variant
   { vec }                                 % suffix
   { \mathbf }                             % decoration
   \use:n                                  % just the argument
 }
\clist_map_inline:nn
 {
  Gamma,Delta,Theta,Lambda,Xi,Pi,Sigma,Phi,Psi,Omega
 }
 {
  \bamboo_define:nnnnN
   { #1 }  % the Greek letter name with first uppercase
   { #1 }  % the Greek letter name with first uppercase
   { mat } % suffix
   { \bm } % decoration
   \use:c  % make a control sequence
 }
\clist_map_inline:nn
 {
  alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,iota,kappa,
  lambda,mu,nu,xi,pi,rho,sigma,tau,phi,chi,psi,omega
 }
 {
  \bamboo_define:nnnnN
   { \tl_mixed_case:n { #1 } } % the Greek letter name with first uppercase
   { #1 }                      % the Greek letter name
   { vec }                     % suffix
   { \bm }                     % decoration
   \use:c                      % make a control sequence
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\Amat \Bmat \Cmat \Avec \Bvec \Cvec$
$\Gammamat \Deltamat \Alphavec \Betavec$
\end{document}
```

[image]

All considered, I believe you lost more time in defining the loops than in defining all commands manually. `;-)` But, of course, academic interest has its role.

Answer (score 1):

The `unicode-math` package [defines them for you, in math mode.](http://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf#23) 𝚨 is `\mbfAlpha`, 𝛍 is `\mbfmu`, 𝜽 is `\mbfittheta`, and so on.

Comment: Thought this dates back, I thougt again about your proposal, but I can't figure how define shortcuts to `\mbf...` constructs using a loop. You answer is good, but I am too much used to my shortcuts now ^^

Comment: @BambOo Without having tested this solution: I think the only thing that doesn’t work is `{alpha,...,omega}`? You should be able to take the existing code and write out the list explicitly: `{alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon}`, but for every letter of the Greek alphabet, and use that in addition to `{a,...,z}`.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Do you mean that e.g. `\mbfalpha` is an alias of `\mathbf{alpha}` when `unicode-math` is loaded ?

Comment: @BambOo Close. `\symbfup{\alpha}`.